# MPVolume view showing different options

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, mpvolumeview

I am using bluetooth sound in my app. I've used MPVolumeview to route between different options. Sometimes it shows 2 options like Bluetooth and iPhone and sometimes showing 3 options like Bluetooth,iPHone,Speaker without doing anything specific or particular. Any help?

Sometimes only iphone and bluetooth device appears, speaker is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the AVAudioSession category has been changed. 
When the category is PlayAndRecord, the MPVolumeView shows "iphone"(it is receiver) and "speaker". 
When the category is not PlayAndRecord such as PlayBack, the MPVolumeView shows "iphone" which means speaker.
Also, the option "DefaultToSpeaker" in PlayAndRecord category will "hide" the "speaker"

Comment: Actually my app is about calling and i tried both voiceChat and videoChat mode, but none is giving all 3 options. Although observed weird thing that if i use videoRecording mode, every time shows all 3 options but then switching between them becomes messy. Also i want like if bluetooth is connected then at starting of call sound should also come form bluetooth only with bluetooth is selected in this MPVolume view.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete answer. The way to activate the receiver is that you both set the category to .PlayAndRecord and the mode to .default or .voiceChat, which makes the MPVolumnView show iPhone and Speaker. You can have a try. When it comes to the .videoRecording mode, i find that when i choose the .allowBluetooth option and connect my bluetooth device, the MPVolumnView will show 2 same bluetooth options, which i guess is a bug. The sound come from bluetooth only when you both connect the bluetooth device and select it in the MPVolumnView.